# how do i extract a partial value from a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want to convert it to just the last two values:

```
(3, 4)
```

In my actual code all four fields are whole numbers but vary greatly in length. I've tried doing this with both regex and 'for' statements as well as trying the various answers to similar questions here on SO but so far no luck.

Comment: you have a tuple, not a string

Comment: String is = `"This is String"` | List = `[1,2,3,4,5]` | Tuple = `(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives you the last two terms in your tuple:

```
>> a = (1,2,3,4)
>> a[-2:]
(3,4)
```

Comment: at first that didn't work but only because I was converting my tuple to a string (oops). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the [slice operator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice).

Edit: Perhaps [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) is a better link.  Scroll down a bit for the slice notation stuff.  The examples deal with strings, but it should work with any sequence type.

Comment: Probably he needs conventional indexing

Answer (score 0):

If (1,2,3,4) is tuple:

```
data = (1,2,3,4)
newData = data[-2:]
```

If you have '(1,2,3,4)' then:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval('(1,2,3,5)')
newData = data[-2:]
```

Or in case you have to split such list in a certain value:

```
def get_slice(inputData, searchVal):   
    if searchVal in inputData and inputData.index(searchVal) < len(inputData):
        return inputData[inputData.index(searchVal)+1:]
    return ()

get_slice((1,2,3,4),2)
```

Comment: ObWarning: `eval()` is evil. (In case he doesn't control where the string is coming from).

Comment: **Nuuuuuu!** use `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: I fully agree with you - it was just a sample in case he has a string mentioned in the question. Sure i know that string could be splited and so on.

Comment: @tim: even when you *do* control where it's coming from, it's evil.  You control it; use `pickle` or `json` or anything else.